Navigating a particular column and parsing out text in attached text in Monday.com
I'm trying to use the API playground in Monday.com to parse out information from a database we have there. There is a field/column called Contacts (with id of 'monday_doc0' which has associated text files which I want to access. I tried this.
query {
  items_by_column_values(
    board_id: xxys
    column_id: "monday_doc0" # ID of the "Contacts" column
    column_value: "" # Leave this empty to fetch all items with any value in the column
  ) {
    id
    name
    column_values(ids: ["monday_doc0"]) {
      id
      text
    }
  }
}

The output is:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Field 'items_by_column_values' doesn't exist on type 'Query'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "query",
        "items_by_column_values"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "undefinedField",
        "typeName": "Query",
        "fieldName": "items_by_column_values"
      }
    }
  ],
  "account_id": xxs
}

I'm struggling to understand the docs well enough. What can I try next?
